# Android Oracle Database JDBC6

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc, connection

Hi i want to create a connection to my Oracle database.
i previously used ojdbc14.jar and everything was working fine, but the connection should be secure and i want to encrypt the files. so i decided to use ojdbc5.jar now.
the jar is im my "libs" folder

Reasons for changing from jdbc14 to jdbc6 i want to use Properties for a secure data exchange between my DB and my devices

earlier i also tried jdbc5 but with this i only got a java Heap Size error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jdbccoonect connect = new jdbccoonect();
        connect.execute();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class jdbccoonect extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String username = "scott";
            String password = "tiger";
            try
            {
                Log.d("HI","HI");
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                            //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");



                /*Connection conn = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin://@10.10.0.9:1521/service",
                                        username, password);*/

                Log.d("HI","HI");
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
01-05 22:27:56.814: D/HI(1610): HI
01-05 22:27:57.005: E/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.005: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 716 (Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;) in Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;
01-05 22:27:57.005: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x002d
01-05 22:27:57.005: I/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.005: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3734: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-05 22:27:57.005: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
01-05 22:27:57.015: I/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.015: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3734: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-05 22:27:57.015: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0094
01-05 22:27:57.015: I/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.015: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3734: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-05 22:27:57.015: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00a8
01-05 22:27:57.015: I/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.015: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3734: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-05 22:27:57.015: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00bc
01-05 22:27:57.015: I/dalvikvm(1610): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
01-05 22:27:57.015: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3734: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-05 22:27:57.015: D/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00d1
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 712 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 712 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 712 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xfa
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: rejected Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;.registerMBeans ()V
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x00fa
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): VFY: rejected Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;.registerMBeans ()V
01-05 22:27:57.025: W/dalvikvm(1610): Verifier rejected class Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;
01-05 22:27:57.035: W/System.err(1610): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
01-05 22:27:57.055: W/System.err(1610): at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-05 22:27:57.055: W/System.err(1610): at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
01-05 22:27:57.055: W/System.err(1610): at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
01-05 22:27:57.055: W/System.err(1610): at at.security.jdbcsecuritydemo.MainActivity$jdbccoonect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
01-05 22:27:57.055: W/System.err(1610): at at.security.jdbcsecuritydemo.MainActivity$jdbccoonect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-05 22:27:57.065: W/System.err(1610): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-05 22:27:57.065: W/System.err(1610): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-05 22:27:57.065: W/System.err(1610): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-05 22:27:57.065: W/System.err(1610): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-05 22:27:57.065: W/System.err(1610): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-05 22:27:57.075: W/System.err(1610): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-05 22:27:57.085: W/System.err(1610): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
01-05 22:27:57.085: W/System.err(1610): ... 11 more
01-05 22:27:57.205: D/gralloc_goldfish(1610): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's Java is different from Oracle's Java. One of the main differences is the class library that differs from the Java Standard Edition (SE).

In your case that means that `ojdbc6.jar` won't run in Android's Java environment because certain Java SE classes are required but not available on Android. The error message mentions `javax.management.MBeanServer`. But I'm pretty sure that's not the only one.

I don't think you can make `ojdbc6.jar` work on Android. It's already surprising that `ojdbc14.jar` works. So stay with it, or redesign your app to go via an intermediary server.