# missing JDBC driver oracle 10g android 4.x

Tags: android, oracle, jdbc, driver

I've got a few problems with my running projet but this one is the worst :

```
    String url="jdbc:oracle:login/pwd@host:1521:etudom";
    Connection co = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        co= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        popUp("Ok");
    }
    // Driver Oracle : Should never happen
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        popUp("ERROR: Oracle Driver's missing");
        //System.exit(1);
    }
    // Internet Connection Problem
    catch (SQLException e) {
        popUp("ERREOR :   " + e.getMessage());
        //System.exit(1);
    }
```

here's the log with OJDBC14 :

```
    01-12 22:37:14.876: D/dalvikvm(558): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    01-12 22:37:16.867: D/gralloc_goldfish(558): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    01-12 22:38:01.996: E/dalvikvm(558): Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.006: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 706 (Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;) in Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;
    01-12 22:38:02.006: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x002d
    01-12 22:38:02.006: I/dalvikvm(558): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.006: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3503: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
    01-12 22:38:02.016: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
    01-12 22:38:02.016: I/dalvikvm(558): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.027: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3503: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
    01-12 22:38:02.027: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0094
    01-12 22:38:02.036: I/dalvikvm(558): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.036: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3503: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
    01-12 22:38:02.036: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00a8
    01-12 22:38:02.036: I/dalvikvm(558): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.036: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3503: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
    01-12 22:38:02.036: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00bc
    01-12 22:38:02.046: I/dalvikvm(558): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3503: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
    01-12 22:38:02.046: D/dalvikvm(558): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00d1
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 702 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 702 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 702 (Ljavax/management/JMException;)
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xfa
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY:  rejected Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;.registerMBeans ()V
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x00fa
    01-12 22:38:02.046: W/dalvikvm(558): VFY:  rejected Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;.registerMBeans ()V
    01-12 22:38:02.056: W/dalvikvm(558): Verifier rejected class Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver;
```

And I always get the ClassNotFound exception and it's driving me crazy!

I used the same Driver for a Command line project and it works well.

If any one have any clue it would be great...

Thanks by advance and sorry for my bad English.

Thomas.

Comment: Do you have Oracle driver .jar in your project's ``libs`` folder?

Comment: Please show the logcat output of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the logcat output. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Newer Oracle drivers (at least `ojdbc6.jar`, maybe earlier ones as well) do not work on Android. They require several classes from the Java Standard Edition (Java SE) that are not available on the stripped down Android platform.

**Update:**

The error message is pretty clear:

```
Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer'
```

This is a Java SE class that's missing on Android. It might want to have a look at the question [Android Oracle Database JDBC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183235/android-oracle-database-jdbc6). This user was able to use *ojdbc14.jar* on Android.

Possibly he/she used the Oracle client differently, e.g. `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");` instead of `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`. Or he/she used a different connection string that internally uses different classes. Or it's an older driver even though is called *ojdbc14.jar* as well.

Anyhow there's no guarantee that it will ever work. Oracle Java client is build for Java SE and not for the Android Java, which only contains those classes that are normally used on a mobile device.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ojdbc14.jar works, at least for basic operations. I don't have any specific knowledge about ojdbc5.jar; you'd have to try it.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work (ojdbc14 & ojdbc5) I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Please show the logcat output. It contains essential information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @user1972624: The link doesn't lead to a page where the logcat output is visible. Please add it to the question. That's where you should have put it anyway when you asked the question in the first place.

Comment: I've add a jar including the javax.management.MBeanServer and I still have the same log so i tried with the solution of Paul Statham but it was not better...